# More Efficient If\Else?

Tags: c#, if-statement, performance, processing-efficiency

Is there possibly a more condensed/efficient way of writing out this if/else statement? I am having to do a check for null on every single field in this database (close to 200 fields) and the code is going to look quite messy by the end. :\

```
if (dr["OLD_NUMBER"] != DBNull.Value)
{
    lblOldNumber.Text = dr["OLD_NUMBER"].ToString();
}
else
{
    lblOldNumber.Text = string.Empty;
}
// A bunch more with different lbls and columns
```

Comment: Hi! I've rolled back your edit because you seem to have added a second question after getting an answer to your first. Instead, you should accept one of the answers to this question, and ask your second question seperately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use the following:

```
lblOldNumber.Text = dr["OLD_NUMBER"] != DBNull.Value ? dr["OLD_NUMBER"].ToString() : string.Empty;
```

More information about the ?: operator instead of if, can be found [here: (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx)

Answer (score 12):

You can get rid of the `if` entirely.

`DBNull.Value.ToString()` returns an empty string.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on this. Am I missing something here? It would still throw an error if ["OLD_NUMBER"] was DBNull.Value

Comment: @JoshuaVolearix: Wrong.  What error do you think it would throw?

Comment: No. Right, The one it continues to throw without it. 
(InvalidCastException)

Comment: @JoshuaVolearix the expression `dr["OLD_NUMBER"].ToString()` is not throwing an InvalidCastException.  If you're seeing one, something else is throwing it.

Answer (score 4):

You could do

```
lblOldNumber.Text = dr["OLD_NUMBER"] != DBNull.Value ? dr["OLD_NUMBER"].ToString() : string.Empty;
```

The above statement would require less lines and looks more readable to me.

Answer (score 1):

```
lblOldNumber.Text = string.Empty;
if (dr["OLD_NUMBER"] != DBNull.Value)
{
    lblOldNumber.Text = dr["OLD_NUMBER"].ToString();
}
```

or you cam make function like

```
void ApplyValue(Label label,object value, string defaultValue){
     label.Text =defaultValue;
     if (value != DBNull.Value)
     {
         label.Text = value.ToString();
     }
}
```

and use next code

```
ApllyValue(lblOldNumber,dr["OLD_NUMBER"],string.Empty);
```

Answer (score 1):

As a rule of thumb when you see this sort of repetition, write a function to do your processing.

```
string FormatIt(object value) 
{
   return value.ToString(); // or whatever the logic is like
}
```

Then:

```
lblOldNumber.Text = FormatIt(dr["OLD_NUMBER"]);
```

So, if you had to modify your code to format money or smth like that, you have **one** place to change.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
var labels = new Dictionary<string, YourLabelClass>
                         {
                             {"OLD_NUMBER", lblOldNumber},
                             //Add your 200 fields here 
                             {"ANOTHER_NUMBER", lblAnotherNumber},
                         };

        foreach (var label in labels)
        {
            label.Value.Text = dr[label.Key].ToString();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the null values from your data set when you query the database.

```
var result = (context.MyTable.Where(c => c.OLD_NUMBER != null));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably write a method:

```
void TextOrNull(object item, Label lbl)
{
  lbl.Text = item != DBNull.Value ? item.ToString() : String.Empty;
}
```

And call it like:

```
TextOrNull(dr["OLD_NUMBER"], lblOldNumber);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would make a method that has this in, something like:

```
private void setLabelText( IDataRecord dr, string columnName, Label label )
{
    label.Text = string.Empty
    if (dr[columnName] != DBNull.Value)
    {
        label.Text = dr[columnName].ToString();
    }
}
```

Then simply call it with the appropriate labels and record names, etc.

```
setText( dr, "OLD_NUMBER", lblOldNumber );
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't experimented with this much but there is an `ItemArray` on the `DataRow` class that will return an object array of the items in the `DataRow`.  Might be able to set up a loop and test values that way rather than hardcoding the name of the key.

Again not sure if this will work as I don't have a test scenario set up on my PC, but like this?

```
foreach (var col in dataRow.ItemArray)
{
    if(DBNull.Value != col)
        lbl.Text = col.ToString()
}
```